# Error when deploying discord.py bot to Heroku: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: deployment, heroku, git, push

so when I'm trying to deploy my discord.py bot to Heroku, it shows following error when executing the last command: > error: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git
I already searched everywhere, but I couldn't find any solutions. Following you will find my cmd commands + output. I really appreciate any help!

```
C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\rubot-git>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Ruben/Desktop/rubot-git/.git/

C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\rubot-git>heroku login
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
Opening browser to []
Logging in... done
Logged in as []

C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\rubot-git>heroku apps:create rubot-host
Creating ⬢ rubot-host... done
https://rubot-host.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/rubot-host.git

C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\rubot-git>heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
Buildpack set. Next release on rubot-host will use heroku/python.
Run git push heroku main to create a new release using this buildpack.

C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\rubot-git>heroku git:remote -a rubot-host
set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/rubot-host.git

C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\rubot-git>git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in bot.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\rubot-git>git commit -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) e1eb173] initial commit
 4 files changed, 32 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 Procfile
 create mode 100644 bot.py
 create mode 100644 requirements.txt
 create mode 100644 runtime.txt.txt

C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\rubot-git>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 913 bytes | 304.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite (from -r /tmp/build_36bc5831/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (to revision rewrite) to /tmp/pip-req-build-jxayyj_3
remote:          Running command git clone -q https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py /tmp/pip-req-build-jxayyj_3
remote:          WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'rewrite', assuming revision or ref.
remote:          Running command git checkout -q rewrite
remote:          error: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q rewrite Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to rubot-host.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/rubot-host.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/rubot-host.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `requirements.txt` file is incorrect. It presumably has a line that looks like

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite
```

which references a Git branch that does not exist.

The package name, with options that you may or may not want to install, is documented in its [README](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py). You should configure your `requirements.txt` accordingly to use a package name, not a Git URL.